# Prove that a group of order $pq$ has a unique Sylow $q$-subgroup and deduce that it is solvable.

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory, solvable-groups

Suppose $p$ and $q$ are prime numbers with EDIT: $q>p$. Prove that a group of order $pq$ has a unique Sylow $q$-subgroup and deduce that it is solvable.

I've found this question in an old past paper and I'm struggling to find the answer and method. Any help/solutions appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I think you have something a bit backwards.  There should be a unique Sylow $p$-subgroup, not $q$-subgroup.  By the Sylow theorems, if we let $n_p$ be the number of $p$-Sylow subgroups, then we have $$n_p \equiv 1 \pmod{p}.$$

But we also have $n_p | q < p$ implying that $n_p = 1$.

EDIT: This is under the assumption that $p$ is the bigger prime.

Comment: Apologies for my typo! I meant $q>p$

Comment: @smallscot, Ah, I had imagined something like that had happened.  Can you see how solubility of the group follows?

Comment: I'm still struggling a little sorry, does $n_p$ being equal to 1, imply commuitivity between composition factors?

Comment: @smallscot, No worries; $n_p = 1$ means that the $p$-Sylow subgroup is normal.  If we let $H$ be this subgroup, then we have that $H$ is normal in $G$.  Since $|H| = p$, $H$ is cyclic and therefore abelian.  Moreover, $|G/H| = q$ so $|G/H|$ is cyclic and therefore abelian, so we have the series $\{1\} \triangleleft H \triangleleft G$, implying $G$ is solvable.

Comment: Ah I see! Thank you for your help :)